# Как собрать OpenSSL под MinGW-w64 в Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, mingw, openssl, mingw-w64

Пробовал несколько найденных в сети инструкций - результат всегда одинаковый:

```
/bin/sh: gcc: command not found
make[1]: *** [Makefile:591: crypto/aes/aes_cbc.o] Error 127
make[1]: Leaving directory '/d/Libraries/Sources/openssl-1.1.0f'
make: *** [Makefile:126: all] Ошибка 2
```

Директории "MSYS2" и "MinGW\mingw32\bin" прописаны в PATH, компилятор рабочий (кучу проектов и других библиотек собрал). Что не так ему с OpenSSL?

Нужны статические lib*.a библиотеки OpenSSL и их инклуды. Подскажите пожалуйста как собрать под Windows (mingw-w64) или, если кто знает где есть уже готовый вариант, поделитесь ссылкой пожалуйста.

Comment: Let me google it for you https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html

Comment: Не прописывайте MSYS2 и путь к компилятору в PATH. Испльзуйте соответствующие оболочки, вызовите нужную через меню пуск: "MSYS2 MinGW 64-bit", оно настроит вам нужное окружение. Более того, в самом окружении MSYS2 поставьте MinGW компилятор. В общем, для начала приложите вывод команды `pacman -Q` ;-)

Comment: @arrowd, Большое спасибо Вам! ))

Comment: @Iceman а чем вам OpenSSL из самого MSYS2 не угодил? :)

Comment: @MonahTuk, хах )))! Да откуда ж я знал, что он там есть! ))) Мне задачу поставили - реализовать ssl в клиенте - у меня сразу мысля: надо собрать openssl... где, как?... )))

Comment: @Iceman `pacman -Ss слово` ;-) или `pacman -Sl` для списка всего добра, что есть.

Comment: @MonahTuk, Спасибо! Обновил пакеты MSYS  с его mingw - добавились libssl.a, libcrypto.a и инклуды.

Comment: @Iceman, можешь мой ответ отметить как решение - там эта информация есть.

Comment: @MonahTuk, конечно! Ещё раз благодарю!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не прописывайте MSYS2 и путь к компилятору в `PATH`.

Используйте соответствующие оболочки, вызовите нужную через меню пуск: **"MSYS2 MinGW 64-bit"**

Оно настроит вам нужное окружение.

Более того, в самом окружении MSYS2 поставьте MinGW компилятор. В общем, для начала приложите вывод команды `pacman -Q`. Если же бегло, то в выводе должен присутствовать:

```
mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc
```

Если же его нет, то нужно:

```
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc
```

Но для начала стоит обновить всё окружение:

```
pacman -Syu
```

Возможно потребуются другие библиотеки для отстройки OpenSSL. Нужно так же ставить `mingw-w64-x86_64-XXX` версии.

К примеру, в самом MSYS2 есть три версии OpenSSL:

- openssl - для Cygwin компилятора
- mingw-w64-x86_64-openssl - для MinGW w64 64-bit
- mingw-w64-i686-openssl - для MinGW w64 32-bit

Для других пакетов это тоже верно. Будьте внимательны и читайте доки, они рулез!

PS Кстати, возможно этих пакетов OpenSSL вам как раз и будет достаточно и не нужно будет собирать самому. Что тоже решение вопроса.

Answer (score 1):

Простой способ - добавить каталог "MinGW/mingw64/bin", и удалить "MinGW\mingw32\bin" в переменную path - нельзя добавлять две версии одной программы в path. Предполагаю, у вас проблема именно из-за конфликта mingw32 и mingw64.

Другой вариант - нужно устанавливать переменные CXX и/или CC при запуске make (или перед запуском): `make -j4 CXX=g++ CC=gcc`. В этом случае  не возникает конфликтов версий компиляторов.